# flock - script done but still locked

Tags: linux, bash, flock

At the beginning of my bash script I run flock to ensure that the script is not run twice at the same time.
Part of the scrip is to show xclock, but as background command. So I see the clock and the script finishes (the clock is still displayed obviously). But when I want to restart the script it doesn't allow me to do so because it is still locked. It seems that the lock is removed only when xclock is closed.

What I don't understand is why the lock remains when I start the x-app as background process and the script finishes. Is the x-app process a child of the process which executes the script?
Here the script

```
#!/bin/bash

fd=200
eval "exec $fd>/tmp/test.lock"
if flock -n $fd; then
  xclock &
else
  echo "locked"
fi
```

I would very much appreciate if someone could explain this?

Thanks,
Ralf

Comment: BTW, what version of bash are you targeting? If it's new enough, you can use some recent syntax extensions to no longer need the `eval`.

Comment: "Is the x-app process a child of the process which executes the script?" - Of course it is. What else would it have as a parent?

Comment: Hey Charles, assumed that the & makes it independent from its parent process. But it shits it to the background only. I am using bash 4.3.11.

Comment: Correct; `&` is not defined or documented to make a process fully independent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `xclock` process inherited the open file descriptor for the lock file, as well as the lock on the file. You can close it in that process by redirecting with `&-`.

```
#!/bin/bash

fd=200
eval "exec $fd>/tmp/test.lock"
if flock -n $fd; then
  eval "xclock $fd>&- &"
else
  echo "locked"
fi
```